# Allowing to select certain amount of checkboxes, based on previous answer

Tags: javascript, checkbox

If i select one from the first checkbox selection, it only allows me to check one teacher and if i select both, it allows me to check two teachers which is how i wanted it to work.

The problem i have is that if i uncheck one of the first checkboxes, i can select any amount of the teachers.

So I would like to sort this issue out and sort of always check how many subjects are selected, and based on that, allow the user to only select that amount of teachers from the second pile of checkboxes.

```js
var count = 0

function countCheckedBoxes(elem) {
  if (german.checked && french.checked) {
    if (elem.checked) {
      if (count <= 2) {
        count = count + 1;
        if (count > 2) {
          count = 2;
          elem.checked = false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      count = count - 1;
      if (count < 0) count = 0;
    }
  } else if (german.checked || french.checked) {
    if (elem.checked) {
      if (count <= 1) {
        count = count + 1;
        if (count > 1) {
          count = 1;
          elem.checked = false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      count = count - 1;
      if (count < 0) count = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font: 13.3333px Arial;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background-color: white;
}

label>span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

input:checked+label {
  color: black;
  animation: bounce 250ms;
}

input:checked+label>span {
  border: 10px solid black;
  animation: bounce 250ms;
}

input:checked+label>span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 4px;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  animation: checked-box 125ms 250ms forwards;
}

@keyframes checked-box {
  /* Animation of the tick symbol */
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: white;
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
  33% {
    width: 4px;
    height: 0;
    border-color: white;
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    width: 4px;
    height: 8px;
    border-color: white;
    transform: translate(0, -8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(.70);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="chooseSubject" style="margin-bottom:24px;">
  <label id="selectSubject" class="form-control">Select your subject(s)</label>
  <table style="width:auto;text-align:left;margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:13px">
    <tr>
      <th style="font:inherit;padding-right:110px;display: flex;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="french" name="subjects[]" value="french" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;">
        <label for="french" style="margin-right:98px;"><span></span>French</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="german" name="subjects[]" value="german" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;">
        <label for="german" style="float:right;"><span></span>German</label>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- TEACHER SELECTION -->

<div id="chooseTeacher" style="margin-bottom:24px;">
  <label id="selectTeacher" class="form-control">Select your teacher(s)</label>
  <table style="width:auto;text-align:left;margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:13px">
    <tr>
      <th style="font:inherit;display:flex;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="teachers[]" value="archer" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
        <label for="archer" style="margin-right:68px;"><span></span>Miss Archer</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="craig" name="teachers[]" value="craig" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
        <label for="craig"><span></span>Miss Craig</label>
      </th>
      <th style="font:inherit;padding-right:110px;display: flex;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="devine" name="teachers[]" value="devine" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
        <label for="devine" style="margin-right:65px;"><span></span>Miss Devine</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="dorrity" name="teachers[]" value="dorrity" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
        <label for="dorrity"><span></span>Miss Dorrity</label>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div><br>
```

Comment: snippet causing error

Comment: @BehradKhodayar Because js part is not in the snippet. :\

Comment: @AdamK. I updated it now, sorry guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause:

Consider this scenario:

Both french & german are checked. we start checking `input[teachers[]]`, But the code doesn't allow for more than two of them remain checked.

Then we uncheck one either french or german. So, after this, any `countCheckedBoxes(elem)` call will fall into the body of `if (german.checked || french.checked)` condition. **First check wont be allowed & count will reset to 1. this is where causes bug.** Now if you check another `input[teachers[]]` element, it will fall into the first inner check of `if (german.checked || french.checked)`{because count=1} & the newly checked element will be allowed to get checked.

---

### Solution:

one solution to this is to uncheck all of `input[teachers[]]` elements while either `french` or `german` is **unchecked**. This will safely restart the process on a virgin land.

---

### UPDATE [Solved]

Previous solution was creating minor bugs & dirty code. So I changed my mind.

The bug was raising because we didn't check `subjects[]` uncheck & it left `count` with the wrong value around.

Just adding an eventlistner for `input[subjects[]]` & reseting elements if detected event was because of unchecking one of `input[subjects[]]` solves the problem.

I also added a check for preventing `checking` `input[teachers[]]` when none of the above are checked. Here it is:

```js
            var count = 0
            
            function resetElements(elem){
                if(elem.checked == false){
                    archer.checked = false;
                    craig.checked = false;
                    devine.checked = false;
                    dorrity.checked = false;
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

            function countCheckedBoxes(elem) {
                if (!(german.checked) && !(french.checked)) {
                    elem.checked = false;
                } else if (german.checked && french.checked) {
                    if (elem.checked) {
                        if (count <= 2) {
                            count = count + 1;
                            if (count > 2) {
                                count = 2;
                                elem.checked = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        count = count - 1;
                        if (count < 0)
                            count = 0;
                    }
                } else if (german.checked || french.checked) {
                    if (elem.checked) {
                        if (count <= 1) {
                            count = count + 1;
                            if (count > 1) {
                                count = 1;
                                elem.checked = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        count = count - 1;
                        if (count < 0)
                            count = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
```

```css
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            label {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                color: #A9A9A9;
                font: 13.3333px Arial;
                position: relative;
            }

            span {
                background-color: white;
            }

            label>span {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                margin-right: 10px;
                border-radius: 3px;
                transition: all 0.3s;
            }

            input:checked+label {
                color: black;
                animation: bounce 250ms;
            }

            input:checked+label>span {
                border: 10px solid black;
                animation: bounce 250ms;
            }

            input:checked+label>span:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 6px;
                left: 4px;
                border-right: 3px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform-origin: 0% 100%;
                animation: checked-box 125ms 250ms forwards;
            }

            @keyframes checked-box {
                /* Animation of the tick symbol */
                0% {
                    width: 0;
                    height: 0;
                    border-color: white;
                    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg);
                }
                33% {
                    width: 4px;
                    height: 0;
                    border-color: white;
                    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg);
                }
                100% {
                    width: 4px;
                    height: 8px;
                    border-color: white;
                    transform: translate(0, -8px) rotate(45deg);
                }
            }

            @keyframes bounce {
                0% {
                    transform: scale(1);
                }
                33% {
                    transform: scale(.70);
                }
                100% {
                    transform: scale(1);
                }
            }
```

```html
<div id="chooseSubject" style="margin-bottom:24px;">
            <label id="selectSubject" class="form-control">Select your subject(s)</label>
            <table style="width:auto;text-align:left;margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:13px">
                <tr>
                    <th style="font:inherit;padding-right:110px;display: flex;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="french" onchange="resetElements(this)" name="subjects[]" value="french" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;">
                        <label for="french" style="margin-right:98px;"><span></span>French</label>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="german" onchange="resetElements(this)" name="subjects[]" value="german" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;">
                        <label for="german" style="float:right;"><span></span>German</label>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        
        <div id="chooseTeacher" style="margin-bottom:24px;">
            <label id="selectTeacher" class="form-control">Select your teacher(s)</label>
            <table style="width:auto;text-align:left;margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:13px">
                <tr>
                    <th style="font:inherit;display:flex;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="teachers[]" value="archer" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                        <label for="archer" style="margin-right:68px;"><span></span>Miss Archer</label>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="craig" name="teachers[]" value="craig" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                        <label for="craig"><span></span>Miss Craig</label>
                    </th>
                    <th style="font:inherit;padding-right:110px;display: flex;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="devine" name="teachers[]" value="devine" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                        <label for="devine" style="margin-right:65px;"><span></span>Miss Devine</label>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="dorrity" name="teachers[]" value="dorrity" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                        <label for="dorrity"><span></span>Miss Dorrity</label>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: How would you write that in javascript?

Comment: @leveeee I just updated it. Please test it. I hope it is what you need